# Is it possible to add a Request Header Value to a Web Server Log using .NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I think the answer is no, but I wanted to check.

I have an Azure App Service MVC .NET app behind a Clousflare WAF. The Source IP addresses that are now in the Web Server Log are those of Cloudflare as opposed to the originating IP. However Cloudflare does pass these original IP addresses on via a request header called "CF-Connecting-IP". In "on prem" IIS, one could had a custom field to add this to the web server log. In Azure App Services this is not possible as it is locked down.

Given the above, is it possible for the .NET app to intercept this value and add it to the access log?

Thanks

Comment: The [HttpResponse.AppendToLog(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.appendtolog?view=netframework-4.7.2) looks like it might be able to do that.

Comment: Thank you for this, however I am unsure whether "Extended Logging Properties" can be set in Azure App Services. Will take a look. A great pointer thanks.

Comment: Was the "Extended Logging Properties" a showstopper? There's an open suggestion on [Azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics/suggestions/6519267-collect-iis-advanced-logs) you might want to upvote.

Comment: Andrew, I have upvoted this. However I think the key issue is being able to add "Custom Properties" and "Extended Loggining Properties" in the first place to App Services, as this is not possible at present due to them being locked down.

Comment: This works....... :) So grateful @andrew-morton. If you create an answer then I will mark as answered. Thanks again. Not sure if many people know this...

Comment: All I did was find the AppendToLog method - you're the current expert on getting it work, so it would be good if you wrote up an answer. Self-answered questions are a (good) thing on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @andrew-morton, ok will do.